# node.js allows undefined arguments in function call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I define a function:

```
function pp(r)
{
    console.log("In Function", r);
    console.log("In Function", q);
    console.log("In Function", m);
}
```

If I execute this - I am able to use the variable q inside the function, even though it is not defined as a function parameter. However in that place if I place another variable - it throws an error.

```
pp('op', q='rr')
In Function op
In Function rr
Uncaught ReferenceError: m is not defined
```

Now if I remove the line `console.log("In Function", q);` I still get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: m is not defined` which is acceptable as q is a named variable.

How am I able to use a variable passed to a function that is not defined in the function parameter?

Comment: `q is a named variable` - no, it isn't ... only r is ... your `q='rr'` is creating a global variable called `q` - that's why it works

Comment: Have you checked 'arguments' in your function, type "!(typeof arguments == 'object' && typeof arguments.length == "number" && arguments.length > 0)" put that into an if condition and return if it's true because no valid parameters have been passed!  If it passes then assign variables to [0], [1], [2] according to length count.

Comment: Use strict mode, always. (ES modules are automatically strict mode.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pp('op', q='rr')` - this is not the right approach. It will create a global variable 'q' with the value 'rr'. That's the reason you are getting the value of q.

one approach is,

```
function pp(r, q='rr', m)
{
    console.log("In Function", r);
    console.log("In Function", q);
    console.log("In Function", m);
}

pp('op') //  r -> op , q -> rr and m is undefined
```

[or] use arguments

```
 function pp()
    {

      if(arguments.length > 0) {
        console.log("In Function", arguments[0]);//op1
        console.log("In Function", arguments[1]);//undefined
        console.log("In Function", arguments[2]);//undefined
    }
  }
    
    pp('op1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Javascript Rest Parameters`. `ES6` provides a new kind of parameter called `Rest Parameter` that has a prefix of `three dots (...)`

**Let's see how to use it:**

```
function pp(r, ...args) { // ...args contains all rest parameters
  console.log("In Function", r); // op
  console.log("All other passed values", args)   // [rr, tt]
  console.log(args[0]) // 0th index value => rr
  console.log(args[1]) // 1st index value => tt
}

pp('op', 'rr', 'tt');
```